# Use a String as an Url in android

Tags: android, string, url, android-activity

I have in android a string, and in this string there is an url.
So now Iput that string into a put.extra, because I want to give that string to an 2. Activity.

Now in the 2. Activity I want to recive my string and use that url , which is in the string, for a new/other string.

How can I done this??

For myself I did an example which you can see under this , but when I run this App get a blank page in the Second Activity! Whats wrong in this code??

Code example:

Activity String definition:

```
private static final String TAG_PURL = "url";
```

Extra and new Intent:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle ();
            bundle.putSerializable(TAG_PURL, purl);

            // Starting new intent
            Intent postin = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), post.class);          
            postin.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(postin);
        }
    });
```

Reciving Extra:

```
Intent postin = getIntent();

            Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
            String purl = (String) bundle.getSerializable (TAG_PURL);
```

Use of the purl String in a new String:

```
private static final String url = TAG_PURL ;
```

Comment: I'm not sure where you are having trouble. Have you tried using it as a url already? That looks like it should work, although I'm not super familiar with the workings of putExtras. You should just be about to write URL u = new URL(url);

Comment: Need to provide more code. Not sure what you are actually doing here.

Comment: Is purl a Url object or a String object? In the case of a Url object, you should be using the getSerializable and then casting to a Url object. If it is actually a string then you should be using bundle.getString() and bundle.putString(). http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html

Comment: the main problem is that i'm getting a blank page ( with screen) and nothing happens, and it is a string object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this if you want:

```
private static final String TAG_PURL = "url";

 Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
 i.putExtra("URL", TAG_PURL);
 startActivity(i);
```

You can get this from your activity b like:

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 String url= extras.getInt("URL");
```

Comment: At the moment i haven't time to test your code, but tomorrow i'll post if it works